# Can I get the classes generated using T4 Templates to inherit from the same class

Tags: t4

I'm writing a small console app to generate some scaffolding code using the *TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor*.

I have a number of .tt files that are used and they all use the same Model from which the values are derived for the individual classes. Following along this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx) I have created another partial class file for the class being created and added a constructor that allows me to pass in the Model.

So, for a class to be generated called `ServiceEntity`, I have a `ServiceEntity.tt` file and a 2nd file called something like `ServiceEntityCode.cs` which contains something like this...

```
partial class ServiceEntity
{
    IServiceConfig _config;

    public ServiceEntity(IServiceConfig config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
}
```

The thing is, I'm having to duplicate this code to create a constructor forr each class I'm generating.

I'd prefer to have something like...

```
class BaseTemplate
{
    IServiceConfig _config;

    public BaseTemplate(IServiceConfig config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
}

partial class ServiceEntity : BaseTemplate
{
    public ServiceEntity() : base() {}
}
```

Can anyone give me a pointer to whether or not such a thing can be achieved and, if it can, where I might find details on how?

**===EDIT===**
Here's a sample template...

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace <#= _config.ServiceEntityNamespace #>
{
    [DataContract()]
    public class <#= _config.ServiceEntityName #> 
    {
        [DataMember()]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [DataMember()]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember()]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The .cs code generated under the .tt file includes this ...

```
public partial class ServiceEntity : ServiceEntityBase
{
//...
}
```

But `ServiceEntityBase` itself doesn't inherit from anything.

Comment: I assume you tried to generate the constructor and inherit the base class in the generated code. Why didn't that work? Can you post the tt file that generates the code as well or something that illustrate the problem? Right now I don't see exactly what you are struggling with.

Comment: The code that is generated doesn't inherit from anything (that was my first thought)

Comment: I've added some additional detail to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
namespace <#= _config.ServiceEntityNamespace #>
{
    [DataContract()]
    public class <#= _config.ServiceEntityName #> : BaseTemplate
    {
        public <#= _config.ServiceEntityName #>() : base() {}

        [DataMember()]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [DataMember()]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember()]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am an ar5e! Thanks @shamp00

Comment: That seemed like the obvious solution. Note that if you like to add code to the generated constructor one can use partial methods for that.